# How to get the time difference between index, multiple invoices - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, diff, timedelta

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` containing multiple invoices from multiple customers.
I would like to find an elegant way to calculate the time between 2 invoices depending on the customer.

My data frame looks as follows (index is the Invoice No, the last column is what I'm expecting):

```
         CustomerID         InvoiceDate  time between 2 orders
index                                  
536365      17850.0 2010-12-01 08:26:00  0 minutes (or np.nat)
536366      17850.0 2010-12-01 08:28:00  2 minutes
536367      13047.0 2010-12-01 08:34:00  0 minutes (It's a new customer)
536369      13047.0 2010-12-01 08:35:00  1 minute
536371      13748.0 2010-12-01 09:00:00  0 minute  (new customer)
536372      17850.0 2010-12-01 09:01:00  33 minutes (see line #2)
536373      17850.0 2010-12-01 09:02:00  1 minute
536374      15100.0 2010-12-01 09:09:00  0 minute
```

This is what I found so far (but obviously it doesn't work !)

```
df = df.sort_values(['CustomerID', 'InvoiceDate']) #To order first according
df = df.set_index('index', drop = True)
for CustomerID in df['CustomerID'].unique():
    index = df.set_index('CustomerID').index.get_loc(CustomerID)
    df['Ordersep'].iloc[index] = df['InvoiceDate'].iloc[index].diff()
```

Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` with `diff()`:

```
df.InvoiceDate = pd.to_datetime(df.InvoiceDate)
df["timedelta"] = df.groupby(["CustomerID"]).InvoiceDate.apply(lambda x: x.diff())

df
    index  CustomerID         InvoiceDate    timedelta
0  536365     17850.0 2010-12-01 08:26:00          NaT
1  536366     17850.0 2010-12-01 08:28:00     00:02:00
2  536367     13047.0 2010-12-01 08:34:00          NaT
3  536369     13047.0 2010-12-01 08:35:00     00:01:00
4  536371     13748.0 2010-12-01 09:00:00          NaT
5  536372     17850.0 2010-12-01 09:01:00     00:33:00
6  536373     17850.0 2010-12-01 09:02:00     00:01:00
7  536374     15100.0 2010-12-01 09:09:00          NaT
```

Comment: Bingo ! Once you see the solution it always seems obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming that you have sorted on customer id and invoice date prior to this (with a little tweaking perhaps)

```
for customer_id in df.CustomerId.unique():
    matching_customer_mask = df.CustomerId == customer_id
    customer_df = df[matching_customer_mask]

    order_times = customer_df.InvoiceDate
    prev_order_times = customer_df.InvoiceDate.shift(1)

    df.loc[matching_customer_mask, 'Ordersep'] = order_times - prev_order_times
```

What this does is it shifts the invoice date column one step down, and then calculates the difference you want.